# Rounding to the nearest nth decimal place with numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, rounding

Can one use `np.around` to the nearest n-th decimal places?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'num':  [0.444, 0.445, 0.446, 0.4, 0.41, 0.49],
                 'near': [0.44, 0.45, 0.45, 0.4, 0.41, 0.49]})

df
Out[199]: 
     num  near
0  0.444  0.44
1  0.445  0.45
2  0.446  0.45
3  0.400  0.40
4  0.410  0.41
5  0.490  0.49
```

##### np.around - nok

```
np.around(df['num'], 2)    
Out[185]: 
0    0.44
1    0.44  # nok
2    0.45
3    0.40
4    0.41
5    0.49
Name: num, dtype: float64
```

##### built-in round on single digit- ok

```
round(0.445,2)

Out[216]: 0.45  # ok
```

##### built-in round on column - nok

```
round(df['num'],2)

Out[218]: 
0    0.44
1    0.44  # nok
2    0.45
3    0.40
4    0.41
5    0.49
Name: num, dtype: float64
```

##### built-in round via lambda on each column cell - ok

```
df['num'].apply(lambda x: round(x,2))

Out[219]: 
0    0.44
1    0.45  # ok
2    0.45
3    0.40
4    0.41
5    0.49
Name: num, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Have you tried `np.ceil` and `np.floor`?

Comment: @CodeDifferent Yes - they do not enable rounding to decimal places afaik.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/5987

Comment: Is your question aimed at printing or more an intermediate step in a calculation? For printing you can use fancy string formatting: f'{x:.2f}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Rounding article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding) on Wikipedia to see the many different rounding rules. The two that are most commonly taught in schools are "round half-up" and "round half away from zero":

```
Half-up             : 1.5 -> 2   -1.5 -> -1
Half-away from zero : 1.5 -> 2   -1.5 -> -2
```

Python's `round` uses the "half-away from zero" rule.

`np.around` does neither - it rounds to the *nearest even integer*. This is documented in the [function's notes](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.around.html) so rounding 0.445 to 0.44 is the expected behavior. The IEEE 754 standard also uses this rule.

---

You can roll your own rounding function:

```py
def my_round(a: np.array, decimals: int) -> np.array:
    factor = 10**decimals
    b = np.abs(a) * factor
    frac = b - np.floor(b)
    return np.where(frac < 0.5, np.floor(b), np.ceil(b)) / factor * np.sign(a)

my_round(df["num"], 2)
```

Comment: Is this function faster / more accurate than built-in round: `df['num'].apply(lambda x: round(x,2))`?

Comment: It seems, when applied to `pd.DataFrame({'num': [random.uniform(10,100) for _ in range(100000000)]})`.

Comment: You should avoid `apply` if you can. It uses slow Python loop. Numpy code is vectorized

Comment: "Python's round uses the "half-away from zero" rule." <- This isn't true, at least for Python 3. It uses round-ties-to-even. See docs here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round, particularly the "rounding is done toward the even choice " wording.